# Firefox 32 and HTML5 video player doesn't show subtitles button

Tags: html, angularjs, firefox, video

I have a question regarding to a HTML5 video player in Firefox

I have the following HTML code

```
<video id="example_video_1" controls preload="metadata"  poster="{{item.Sketch.videoimg}}">
<source src="{{item.Sketch.mp4}}" type='video/mp4' />
<track kind="subtitles" src="{{item.Sketch.subs}}" srclang="en" label="English" ></track>
</video>
```

Where the text between {{}} are angularjs variables.

This is actually working fine in Chrome and IE but in Firefox 32 is not whowing the subtitles button. If I add the "default" tag to the  the subtitles are played always but the user cannot turn them off.

There isn't specific javascript for the video on my page.

Anybody can help me?